# Migrating azure subscription from CSP to pay as you go

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We currently have an Azure account set up through a third party who happens to be a CSP. As expected, this took several hours to set up and configure.

We're looking to move from that CSP partner to an account that we manage ourselves. The feedback we're getting is that that's not something easily done.

Has anyone experienced difficulties moving from a CSP to a pay as you go subscription, or is this company we're dealing with holding something back? I obviously want to avoid the several hours of re-setting up all of our resources.

Comment: Are you looking to take over the CSP's existing Subscription?

Answer (score 1):

Migrating resources across accounts are not something I have seen done. But you may get the Azure resource manager template for each resource. See attached link.

At the same time I would encourage you to implement infrastructure as code as part of your best practice for development in your organization. Infrastructure as Code is a process of managing and provisioning computing infrastructure in Azure with some declarative approach while setting their configuration using definition files instead of traditional interactive configuration tools.

The key benefits of IaC are:

- Consistently achieve standardised provisioning or deployment
- Accelerating provisioning or deployment rapidly
- Reusable JSON code for repeatable or similar provisioning or deployment
- Extensible JSON code for incorporating with additional items

Export template:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template

Infrastructure as code: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/02/11/iac-on-azure-an-introduction-of-infrastructure-as-code-iac-with-azure-resource-manager-arm-template/